# Pulling Variable Data in Database with IN/LIKE, using TRIM, or CONTAINS in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax

So the problem that I have run into may be a problem that has been asked before but I have some supplemental questions to add to it. I've seen other Stackoverflow questions in regards to the inability to use IN and LIKE in the Where clause. The only problem is that I am trying to steer away from using LIKE and OR, because in PHP I am putting data into an array and imploding the data with (`','`) so I can use `IN`, in some instances the data could be 100s of entrys and it just doesnt seem safe to use `LIKE` with the possibility of a variety of combinations. I've had someone at work mention that I could use `TRIM`, but I feel like that wont solve my issue. With that said, let me provide some insight.

I pull data from a directory where the username is `[UserName]`, this username or in some cases, multiple user names gets stored into an array and a while loop runs to get Room Numbers based off the username. The problem is that this table (Which is Read-Only, and apparently no one knows who has access to make changes) that contains room numbers has the username as `[  UserName]`. Because of it, I will never get that data because `[UserName]` and `[  UserName]` are obviously not the same.

I need to find a way to write a more solid query that basically looks at each username like this: `%UserName%`

Or just pretty much negates the white spaces in the database while using a `WHERE/IN` clause (or something similar).

Comment: How would using `TRIM` not solve your issue?

Comment: Might not be a good idea to call yourself `Code Newby` if you are actually working in `IT` btw.

Comment: "I could use TRIM, but I **feel** like that wont solve my issue. "  Ah, the Dr. Phil school of programming, I see.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Haha you are right, but I'm very humble in my inexperience writing code. I've been more of a hardware guy. Maybe one day I can be code expert

Comment: @DigitalChris Haha you know it, but really, I wasn't sure. I just tried my best to figure out what needed to do, I was just unsure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fail to see how using `TRIM` will not work...

Option 1:

```
SELECT u.*, TRIM(u.username) as username_canonical
FROM user u
WHERE TRIM(u.username) = ?
```

Option 2:

```
SELECT u.*, TRIM(u.username) as username_canonical
FROM user u
HAVING username_canonical = ?
```

With either of those you could still use an `IN` clause in addition to you username criteria.

Comment: Thank you for actually supplying an answer. After doing some reading I must have been confused on TRIM's actual function. Thank you for clarifying this for me.